# I have a db with table Organisations and another table Sites. How can I use Flask-WTF map new sites created to an organisation

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a one-to-many relationship created but I am not sure how I can post the organization that has been selected from the dropdown menu with the new site details that have been created.

Basic page layout will be dropdown containing organization names that have already been created and stored in the organization table in the db. End-user selects an organization then types in the new name for a site and clicks submit.

Code is below and any help will be most appreciated.

App.py

```
@app.route('/add_site')
def add_site():
    """ Find and show field from db for the user to fill in """

    form = AddSite()
    organisations = db.session.query(Organisation)
    return render_template('add_site.html', form=form, 
    organisations=organisations)


@app.route('/insert_site', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insert_site():
    """ Insert populated fills from add_site to db """

    form = AddSite()
    site_name = Site(site_name=form.site_name.data)
    db.session.add(site_name)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('get_org'))
```

forms.py

```
class AddSite(FlaskForm):
    """ Adding new site """

    site_name = StringField('Site Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Site')
```

Models.py

```
class Organisation(db.Model):
    """ Table to store organisation details """

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, 
    unique=True)
    org_name = db.Column(db.String())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    sites = db.relationship('Site', backref='org_name', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, org_name):
        self.org_name = org_name


class Site(db.Model):
    """ Table to store site details """

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    site_name = db.Column(db.String())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'))

    def __init__(self, site_name):
        self.site_name = site_name
```

add_site.html

```
<form action=" {{url_for('insert_site') }}" method="POST" class="col-12">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

      <div class="col s12">

        <select name="organisation_list">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an 
            Organisation</option>
            {% for org in organisations %}
            <option value ="{{org.org_name}}">{{org.org_name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <label>Organisations</label>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            {{ form.site_name.label }}
            {{ form.site_name(size=32) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <buttom>
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </buttom>
    </div>
</form>
```

The end result is to map multiple sites to a organization. This is so I can create a page which will show all the sites that are under an organization.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear as to what you want to do exactly and how you need help.

Comment: The html page shows the list of organizations in a dropdown menu. When I go to add a new site I am unsure how I can pass the data back for the organization selected in the dropdown menu back to the db on submission of the form to say this site is linked to this organization. I have put in the one-to-many relationship between the two tables in models.py, but when I add a new site the org_id column is just showing ```null``` when it should be showing the ID for the organization that was selected in the dropdown. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Did you try out my solution.

Comment: @kellymandem Yes thank you very much for the scripts. But having trouble now with the HTML part. How do I display each organization in the dropdown menu? Sorry very new to Python and Flask still very much learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your scripts

**App.py**

```
from flask import (request, render_template, redirect_url,
                   url_for)
from app.Models import db, Site  # Use proper import here for your app


@app.route('/add_site', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_site():
    form = AddSite(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        site = Site(
            site_name=form.site_name.data,
            org_id=form.organisation.data
        )
        db.session.add(site)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('get_org'))
    return render_template('add_site.html', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as Form
from wtforms import (SelectField, StringField, SubmitField)
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired as Required
from app.Models import Organisation  # Use proper import here for your app


class AddSite(Form):
    """ Adding new site """

    site_name = StringField('Site Name',
                            validators=[Required('Site name is required')])
    organisation = SelectField('Organisation', coerce=int,
                               validators=[
                                   Required('Please select an organisation')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Site')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddSite, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        organisations = Organisation.query.with_entities(
            Organisation.id, Organisation.org_name). \
            order_by(Organisation.org_name).all()
        self.organisation.choices = [
            (organisation.id, organisation.org_name)
            for organisation in organisations
        ]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Organisation(db.Model):
    """ Table to store organisation details """

    __tablename__ = 'organisation'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True,
                          default=datetime.utcnow)
    sites = db.relationship('Site', backref='organisation', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Organisation: {!r}'.format(self.org_name)


class Site(db.Model):
    """ Table to store site details """

    __tablename__ = 'site'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    site_name = db.Column(db.String())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True,
                          default=datetime.utcnow)
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Site: {!r}'.format(self.site_name)
```

**add_site.html**

```
<form action=" {{url_for('add_site') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group{% if form.site_name.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form.site_name.label(for_='site_name') }}
        {{ form.site_name(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.site_name.errors %}
            <span class="help-block">{{ form.site_name.errors[0] }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group{% if form.organisation.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form.organisation.label }}
        {{ form.organisation(class='form-control') }}
    </div>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-default', value='Add Site') }}
</form>
```

Comment: thankyou very much for the scripts. Having trouble now with the HTML part. How do I display each organization in the dropdown menu? Sorry very new to Python and Flask still very much learning.

Comment: @tony25225 Just change the code in `forms.py` and `add_site.html` to what I gave you and everything will work just fine and also make sure you use proper statements according to your project setup.